# combine SURF detector with a different descriptor

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I want to compute a descriptor based on the multi-scale detected SURF points. When I use Matlab function 'detectSURFFeatures', I can get the detected points with scale information. But according to the point scale, how can I get the scaled image where the point is detected. So if I got a SURF point with scale 1.7, how can I get the image with scale 1.7?

I saw that brisk descriptor was combined with SURF detector to achieve scale invariant property. so after getting the SURF points with scale information, should the brisk descriptor be computed at the multi-scale images where these points are detected? so how to get the multi-scale images according to the given point scales?

Comment: I'm not sure why do you want to scale the image, but `imscale` can help.

Comment: because I want to get a scale invariant feature descriptor. so the feature descriptor should be computed at the scaled image where the feature point is detected, is that right?

Comment: I think scale-invariant should mean that it will give more or less the same variable without scaling the image. As in SIFT, it scales the image inside the code. So you don't have to manipulate the image itself. Not sure about SURF though.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the `extractFeatures` function to compute a different descriptor from `SURFPoints` by specifying a `'Method'` parameter. You have a choice of `'BRISK'` and `'FREAK'`. `extractFeatures` will handle the scale for you.